# Prometheus alert test issue

Tags: prometheus

I'm using Prometheus 2.5 and following the tutorial on tests here https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/2.5/configuration/unit_testing_rules/ I get

```
user@nb ~/Downloads/prometheus-2.5.0.linux-amd64 $ ./promtool check rules test.yml
Checking test.yml
  FAILED:
yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 4: field rule_files not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups
  line 7: field evaluation_interval not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups
  line 9: field tests not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups
```

I created alerts.yml and test.yml as specified in the tutorial.
  Not sure where to find rulefmt.RuleGroups or how to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check rules` is a syntax check for a rules files. You want `test rules` to run PromQL unittests.

Comment: thanks, sry about this, should've noticed it earlier